# using macro to send reports via email with gridline borders between records

Tags: ms-access, macros, ms-access-2007

I do not knw VBA and would like to know if I can, with my limited knowledge,  use the send-object command (or another command)to email Access reports,  with gridline borders in between the fields in my output.  I currently have the macro email format set to html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If snapshot format is not an option for you (it requires that your users install a free utility), then you must build the html yourself in code, adding suitable tables. Given your previous question, this may well be the route to take, but it requires quite a bit of coding, though not necessarily in VBA.

Comment: In A2007 and A2010 PDF output is a built-in option.

Answer (score 0):

As I am having the same problem, I have been looking around and creating an HTML or your own RTF document seems to be the way to go. RTF is *not that complicated*, but it still requires you to know BASIC programming.

Now, HTML is easy enough for me and I can easily add borders in HTML. (It's a bit harder in RTF syntax, to my point of view.)

Anyway, once you have that file ready, you need to send it and for that you need to somehow access MAPI or something of the sort. For that I found this page at Microsoft:

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=161088

It includes a sample function that sends a message of any size with any number of parameters in the header and any number of attachment. All of which cannot be done with the default SendObject function.